# How to receive more than 10 amazon SQS message programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We have SQS Standard Message Queue and its growing very fast. most of time we receiving old notification. We have configure Message Retention Period for 2 days.
Is there any way to receive more than 10 messages programmatically.
Following is my code to revive SQS Messages from amazon.

```
private IEnumerable<Message> getMessagesFromQ(string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKey, string myQueueURL)
    {
        using (var amazonSQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
        {

            ReceiveMessageRequest recieveMessageRequest =
                new ReceiveMessageRequest();

            recieveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myQueueURL;
            recieveMessageRequest.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10;

            ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse =
                amazonSQSClient.ReceiveMessage(recieveMessageRequest);

            return receiveMessageResponse.Messages;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just call it multiple times!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
We did the same.before posting. I want to know is there any other way(suggested by amazon i.e any other method) to receive more than 10 message in one request.

Answer (score 6):

As per the documentation, [10 is the maximum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) per request.

To increase message processing throughput in SQS, extra queue readers are typically added.

Comment: Thank you for you response.
Can you please elaborate  "extra queue readers "?
I have called getMessagesFromQ in loop.Is this Correct? Or any other well known way is there?

Comment: I mean, call getMessagesFromQ from multiple threads (or multiple servers)

Comment: Yes, since yesterday we are doing same

Comment: Multiple threads may lead to process same message twice or thrice, i guess.

Comment: @SatyamGupta yes so the processing logic should be idempotent. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html `Design your applications to be idempotent (they should not be affected adversely when processing the same message more than once).`

Comment: You can also use FIFO queues for [exactly once processing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-exactly-once-processing) _FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queues are designed to enhance messaging between applications when the order of operations and events is critical, or where duplicates can't be tolerated_ .  The tradeoff here is that you're limited to 20k in flight messages for a FIFO queue